# convert oracle date format

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Exploring machine learning & with in training set I have oracle timestamp as below 07-FEB-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM for input.

Tried below

```
data['OPENDT'] = pd.to_datetime(data.OPENDT)
or
data['OPENDT'] = data['OPENDT'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Is there a way strip 12.00.00.000000000 AM (as it is same across diff values in dataset) & convert date to integer?

Want to feed OPENDT as integer for the input.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.to_datetime(data.OPENDT, format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.000000000 %p')
               \.values.astype(int) // 3600000000000
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to convert datetime format to integer?

Comment: Integer of what? Seconds, hours, years?

Comment: Integer of hours.

Comment: I get below error.AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'